# Detecting plug/unplug of headphones in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to detect when a user pluggs or unpluggs the headphones on wp7?

The problem is that when a song is playing on a background AudioPlayerAgent and the user plugs on unplugs the phones, the `protected override void OnUserAction` method of the AudioPlayerAgent receives a pause UserAction and pauses the music.

I need to detect the plug/unplug on the UI thread so I can update the GUI to reflect a paused state.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question? check the PlayState of the agent when OnUserAction is fired. if it's paused, update the UI as paused.

Comment: @willmel Is not that easy. On WP7 the Communication Between Foreground Application and Background Agent is not linear. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202944(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the PlayStateChanged event of the BackgroundAudioPlayer within your page:

```
    public void MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayStateChanged += InstanceOnPlayStateChanged;
    }

    private void InstanceOnPlayStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // Update UI
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there currently is any API to query the current state of the head phones.

You might be able to hack a solution to your problem using the Media element. The Media element will raise an CurrentStateChanged event whenever the headphones are unplugged, so you might be able to hook up on this event to change the state of your GUI. It's not the most elegant solution, but it might but the only way at the moment.

Comment: I added a MediaElement to the .xaml.cs file and subscribe the CurrentStateChanged event but it's not triggered when I unplug the headphones. It's probably because that MediaElement is not playing anything at all.